# I am unable to configure my eclipse ide for android application development

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am unable to configure my eclipse ide for android application development. I am using eclipse neon and my jdk version is jdk 1.8.0_91. The following errors are being shown:- 
1>In the activity_main.xml page its showing the error java.lang.NullPointer Exception 
2> Failed to load AppCompact Actionbar with unknown error 3>android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorBar failed to instantiate 
4>Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130771996 and 2130772027. 
I also changed the path in the system environment variables but its not working. 
Please help resolve these issues.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBY1G4-mfbBRjUtNWtIcmhPTG8
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBY1G4-mfbBbmd4X0dHSkJOM1k

Comment: try to follow step by step the oficial tutorial https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: Don't use Eclipse ADT support closed by Google use Android Studio for Development.